# Unrecognized field "class" in Jackson conversion

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a java class that contains an array of sub-classes as such:

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo(use = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "class", visible = true)
public class Zoo {
  Date stamp=new Date();

  public Date getStamp() {
    return stamp;
  }

  public void setStamp(Date stamp) {
    this.stamp = stamp;
  }

  List<Animal> animals;

  public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
    return animals;
  }

  public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
  }
}
```

When I instantiate this class with multiple animals types and convert it using jackson's new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(zoo), I get the following string:

```
{
  "stamp": 1556129201484,
  "animals": [
    {
      "class": "com.test.Cat",
      "title": "Tom"
    },
    {
      "class": "com.test.Dog",
      "title": "Jerry"
    },
  ]
}
```

When I try to convert this json string back to an object using: new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, Zoo.class), I get the following error:

Unrecognized field "class" (class com.test.Cat), not marked as ignorable

Not sure how to configure the mapper to recognize this field as the sub-class type of Animal. I tried using class ListofAnimals extends ArrayList { }; but that did not work either.

Any ideas on how to perform this conversion?

Comment: Can you share the Animal class here.

Comment: @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo(use = CLASS, include = PROPERTY, property = "class", visible = true)
public class Animal {
  String title;
  public String getTitle() { return title;}
}

Comment: and btw the Animal class has subclass definitions:  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),

Comment: Using om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); seems to work but I still find this to be very stranage

Comment: @jvence Were you able to solve it properly? I am facing the same issue..

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk Try using om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Comment: While this works as workaround, I think the proper way is to use visible=false. This will keep the field in serialized json, but won't try to parse it. @see javadoc for visible.